# Haskell. How this function catch negative numbers as a parameter?

Tags: haskell

I don't understand, how this function negative numbers catchs?

```
mdrop 0 []    = []
mdrop 0 (h:t) = h:t
mdrop n []    = []
mdrop n (h:t) = mdrop (n-1) t
```

If my input looks like this `mdrop (-3) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 88, 6]`
I receive an empty list. But I don't understand in which line catches the negative number.

Comment: Try to evaluate it on paper for (-3) and [1] and you will see.  (-3) and nonempty list goes to last pattern and recursively lowers `n` and cuts off list's head leaving it empty and activating third pattern.

Btw, what does it exactly mean that "function is secure against negative numbers"?

Comment: I think he means "defined" instead of "secured".

Comment: @Haskell could you edit your question to be more specific and fix the wording&spelling?

Comment: @radrow I have corrected, It is okay so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing catches the negative number specifically, but decreasing `n` is *always* accompanied by a shorter list, so eventually you  hit the empty list and the 3rd equation matches. `n` is an example of an irrefutable pattern; it will match *any* number (positive, zero, or negative), although with the given definition, it will never be checked until you've already confirmed that the first argument is non-zero.

Effectively, a negative argument produces the same result as a sufficiently large argument, in that it can always be decremented without reaching 0.

Tracing it manually,

```
     mdrop (-3) [1,2,3,4,5,7,88,6] 
  == mdrop (-4) [2,3,4,5,7,88,6]
  == mdrop (-5) [3,4,5,7,88,6]
  == mdrop (-6) [4,5,7,88,6]
  == mdrop (-7) [5,7,88,6]
  == mdrop (-8) [7,88,6]
  == mdrop (-9) [88,6]
  == mdrop (-10) [6]
  == mdrop (-11) []
  == []
```

---

As an aside, your first two definitions could be replaced by the single definition

```
mdrop 0 xs = xs
```

since in both original definitions, you simply return the second argument when you the first matches 0.

Comment: Thanks für the explanation. I have another question. Is there a possibility to catch negative numbers without using if else or guards in this code. only purely pattern matching?   What menas secend line  (h:t) = h:t list with one element?

Comment: 1) Types like `Int` don't have broad patterns to match; you can only match individual elements or an arbitrary element. You need to use a guard. 2) The pattern `(h:t)` matches a singleton list like `[1]` by equating `h = 1` and `t = []`, since `[1]` is just syntactic sugar for `1:[]`.